# Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.tenantIdentifierResolver'

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, multi-tenant

I'm making my code multi-tenant with Schema based distinction. I've done most part, but my spring-boot application doesn't start up. Essentially, during the start of my application, I have a default dataSource, during the run-time, I set the TenantContext with a tenantId I get in the request, I don't know if I'm doing it right.

Below is the code:

```
@Configuration
```

@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfig implements TransactionManagementConfigurer {

```
@Autowired
MFSConfiguration mfsConfiguration;

@Autowired
HealthCheckRegistry healthCheckRegistry;

@Autowired
ApplicationContext applicationContext;

private ConcurrentMap<String, DataSource> dataSourceMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();


@Override
public PlatformTransactionManager annotationDrivenTransactionManager() {
    return transactionManager();
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getNativeEntityManagerFactory());
    transactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource());
    transactionManager.setDefaultTimeout(mfsConfiguration.getIntProperty("default.timeout"));
    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean(name = "customEntityManagerFactory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManager.setDataSource(dataSource());
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = getHibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    entityManager.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
    entityManager.setJpaPropertyMap(hibernateProperties());
    entityManager.setPackagesToScan(mfsConfiguration.getProperty("xxxx.packages.scan"));
    entityManager.setPersistenceUnitName(mfsConfiguration.getProperty("xxxx.persistence.unit.name"));
    entityManager.setPersistenceXmlLocation(mfsConfiguration.getProperty("xxxx.persistence.unit.location"));
    entityManager.setJpaDialect(new HibernateJpaDialect());
    entityManager.setPackagesToScan("com.xxxx.mfs.txn");
    return entityManager;
}

@Bean
public MultiTenantConnectionProvider tenantConnectionProvider() {
    MultiTenantConnectionProvider tenantConnectionProvider = new MultiTenantConnectionProvider(healthCheckRegistry, mfsConfiguration, applicationContext);
    tenantConnectionProvider.selectDataSource(TenantContext.getCurrentTenant());
    return tenantConnectionProvider;
}

@Bean
@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public RequestBasedTenantIdentifier tenantIdentifierResolver() {
    RequestBasedTenantIdentifier requestBasedTenantIdentifier = new RequestBasedTenantIdentifier();
    return requestBasedTenantIdentifier;
}

private Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties() {
    Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties = new HashMap<>();
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.multiTenancy", "SCHEMA");
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider", tenantConnectionProvider());
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver", tenantIdentifierResolver());
    return hibernateProperties;
}

private HibernateJpaVendorAdapter getHibernateJpaVendorAdapter() {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
    jpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(mfsConfiguration.getBooleanProperty("show.sql", false));
    return jpaVendorAdapter;
}

private DataSource dataSource() {
    if (TenantContext.getCurrentTenant() == null) {
        TenantContext.setCurrentTenant(mfsConfiguration.getProperty("xxxx.database.default.tenantId", "default"));
    }
    if (dataSourceMap.get(TenantContext.getCurrentTenant()) == null) {
        dataSourceMap.put(TenantContext.getCurrentTenant(), tenantConnectionProvider().selectDataSource(TenantContext.getCurrentTenant()));
    }
    return dataSourceMap.get(TenantContext.getCurrentTenant());
}
}
```

My request based tenant identifier is like this:

```
public class RequestBasedTenantIdentifier implements CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver {

TenantContext tenantContext;

@Override
public String resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() {
    String tenantId = TenantContext.getCurrentTenant();
    if(tenantId==null){
        tenantId = "default";
    }
    return tenantId;
}

@Override
public boolean validateExistingCurrentSessions() {
    return true;
}
```

My tenant context class looks like this:
    public class TenantContext {

```
private static ThreadLocal<String> currentTenant = new ThreadLocal<String>()
{
    @Override
    protected String initialValue() {
        return "default";
    }
};

public static void setCurrentTenant(String tenant) {
    currentTenant.set(tenant);
}

public static String getCurrentTenant() {
    return currentTenant.get();
}

public static void clear() {
    currentTenant.remove();
}
}

The exception stack-trace is below:
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories]: Factory method 'repositories' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shiftBasedEmployeeRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.tenantIdentifierResolver': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
... 152 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shiftBasedEmployeeRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.tenantIdentifierResolver': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1060)
at org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories.cacheRepositoryFactory(Repositories.java:95)
at org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories.populateRepositoryFactoryInformation(Repositories.java:88)
at org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories.<init>(Repositories.java:81)
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.repositories(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.java:182)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.rest.SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ab165922.CGLIB$repositories$5(<generated>)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.rest.SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ab165922$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$4101d928.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.rest.SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ab165922.repositories(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
... 153 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.tenantIdentifierResolver': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:355)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.getTarget(CglibAopProxy.java:687)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:637)
at com.xxxx.mfs.txn.multitenancy.RequestBasedTenantIdentifier$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$49293760.resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier(<generated>)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$SessionBuilderImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1293)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.withOptions(SessionFactoryImpl.java:702)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl.internalGetSession(EntityManagerImpl.java:115)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.postInit(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:174)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl.<init>(EntityManagerImpl.java:83)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.internalCreateEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:319)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:286)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.invokeProxyMethod(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:407)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean$ManagedEntityManagerFactoryInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:560)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy128.createEntityManager(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:288)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy142.getDelegate(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.provider.PersistenceProvider.fromEntityManager(PersistenceProvider.java:295)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.<init>(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:58)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.createRepositoryFactory(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:79)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.doCreateRepositoryFactory(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:69)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.TransactionalRepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.createRepositoryFactory(TransactionalRepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:72)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:227)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
... 174 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131)
at org.springframework.web.context.request.AbstractRequestAttributesScope.get(AbstractRequestAttributesScope.java:41)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:340)
... 204 common frames omitted
```